# query load page go instantly to div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have problem with scroll. Its working fine, but i want to make it instantly without any animation, just then page refreshing be the same place as before without scrolling to the place.

my js code.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(window).scrollTop( $("#col-6").offset().top)

    });
</script>
```

My project structure for example.

First including css and html

```
    <?php 

    include(html/css.php);
    some code....
     <div class=col-6> 
     some code....
    </div>
    include(footer.php);
    ?>
```

so in footer php after

```
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5fbb5e690d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

i use my js code.

And after page load its scrolling to col-6 div. But, i want instantly  without any animation or scrolling be in what place.

What i try

```
<script>
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
        $('body').hide();
        $(window).( $("#col-6").offset().top)
    });
</script>
```

any1 have solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you use jQuery, your can use `.animate()` with an animation delay of zero milliseconds (instantaneous).

That is `.animate([property], [delay], [callback])`.

To make sure to hide the very quick scroll effect, you can hide the whole page (using the CSS `opacity` at zero), then after the scroll has completed,  restore the opacity.

[Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // hide the whole page
  $("html").css({opacity:0})
  
  // scroll and unhide the page using the complete callback
  $("html").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#scroll_to_me").offset().top
  }, 0, ()=>$("html").css({opacity:1}))
})
```

```css
.space {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="space"></div>
<div id="scroll_to_me">HERE</div>
<div class="space"></div>
```

Comment: this a bit faster, but same thing. I can see scrolling to my div.

Comment: I edited with the `complete` callback...

Comment: I think, because my code including in last part js its not hiding the whole page.